# Plotly Express Bar Chart Race not working as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plotly, plotly-express

I'd like to produce an animated bar chart for the dataset below. I created a static bar chart through:

```
 plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

 graph = sns.countplot(data=enrich, x="Username")

 plt.box(on=None)

 graph.set_title("Q3 Enrichment", fontsize=30, pad=40)

 graph.set_xlabel("CEE", fontsize=10)

 graph.set_xticklabels(graph.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

So, I'd like to the count 'Username' and using the 'Date Completed' as either the bar label or as the slider.

```
Stock Number    PSF_ID      Project         Hero / Non-Hero Date   completed    Username        Team
694009         PSF_438980   SSE - RS PRO 2     Hero             01/10/2019     Name 1         RS PRO
1368299        PSF_438933   SSE - RS PRO 2     Hero             01/10/2019     Name 2         II&T
1774499        PSF_421233   RS PRO NPI         Hero             01/10/2019     Name 3         RS PRO
```

**This is the code I've used so far to no avail for the bar chart race:**

```
enrich = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.bar(enrich, x="Username", color="royal_blue",
      animation_frame="Date completed", range_y=[0,500])
fig.show()
```

This code doesn't seem to work on just one axis. I'd like to use (X- 'Username'), as the Y-axis will just be the count.